# How do I uppercase the first character in a TextBox?

Tags: vb.net

How do I uppercase the first character in a TextBox? I'm using VB.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ToTitleCase](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312897) method,

```
Dim curCulture As CultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
Dim tInfo As TextInfo = curCulture.TextInfo()
Dim title as String = "converted using textinfo"
Console.WriteLine(tInfo.ToTitleCase(title))
```